Firebase Error: export 'default' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/compat/app' (module has no exports)
I recently upgraded Firebase to 10.12.4 and now have this error which isn't allowing me to compile.
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/database";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import "firebase/compat/storage";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  databaseURL: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
  measurementId: "xxx",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: false, cacheSizeBytes: firebase.firestore.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED, merge: true });

export const storage = firebase.storage(); 
export default firebase;

This has worked with no problems in the past - but am wondering why it now throwing this error, and how to fix it?

The new firebase documentations suggests upgrading from namespace API to modular API.
You can check the documentation on firebase docs.


import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";


//similarly for auth
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth'

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY ,
  databaseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);

const auth = getAuth(app);

const db = getFirestore(app);

const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export {app, database, auth};



Be sure to add credentials in the environment file.
And If you still need to use the compat version, I didn't found firebase/compat/app on npmjs available packages. Try using firebase/app-compat, firebase/firestore-compat, firebase/auth-compat, etc.
